# Android progress dialog for Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog

I have an activity with a listview. When I call this activity the activity takes about 3-5 seconds to appear and display the listview. It looks as if the button has not been pressed to load the activity, i would like to display a progressdialog while this loads but can't figure it out.

```
ProgressDialog progress;
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading maps!",
        "Please wait...", true);


    // sort out track array
    getTracks();

            progress.dismiss();
```

I did the above on the oncreate() of the activity with the listview but the dialog never shows?

What I would like is to show the progress dialog on Activity A when the button is pressed and then dismiss once Activity B is loaded and displayed?

Thanks

Comment: You should use asynctask to display progress while work with it and use async task method

Comment: If your `getTracks()` is using some AsyncTask, you need to put your `progress.dismiss();` an the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement AsyncTask or simple JAVA threading. Go with AsyncTask right now.

- `onPreExecute()` - display dialog here
- `doInBackground()` - call getTracks()
- `onPostExecute()` - display tracks in ListView and dismiss dialog

For example:

```
private static class LoadTracksTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

       progress = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
       progress .setMessage("loading");
       progress .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         // do tracks loading process here, don't update UI directly here because there is different mechanism for it
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

       // write display tracks logic here
       progress.dismiss();  // dismiss dialog
    }
}
```

Once you are done with defining your AsyncTask class, just execute the task inside `onCreate()` by calling `execute()` method of your AsyncTask.

For example:

```
new LoadTracksTask().execute();
```

Comment: Yes,Paresh is right you have to use AsyncTask for filling your data into listview.

Comment: yes ok this looks cool but when I create the ProgressDialog(this....I can't use this because that applies to the class. Calling MainGame.this also doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make progress Dialog like this :

```
onPreExecute(){
    progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
     progressdialog.setMessage("Please wait while downloading application from the web.....");
     progressdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
     progressdialog.setMax(100);
     progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
     progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
     progressdialog.show();
}
doInBackground(String... strings){

// here you code for downloading
}

onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
{
// here set progress update 
progressdialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
onPostExecute(String result)
{
progressdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: In mobile device, you can't decide how long it takes to fetch tracks, because this kind of process is depend on the configuration of device and network connection.

Comment: BTW, all those methods belongs to which class? Incomplete detail/code.

Comment: ya it depends on network connection if we wanna download something we should have network connection.so that progress update method will indicate us how long it will take to download if wifi connection's range is in low it will take time.

Comment: Yeah all I want to show is a dialog instead of nothing as when i watch people use it they keep pressing the button as if it hasnt registered where as I know it is getting info from the database. It doesn't matter  whether it takes 5 or 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
private static class MapLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // make your element GONE
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Load map processing
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Document> result) {

        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        adapter.setNewData(new_data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In your onCreate() use:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
new MapLoader.execute();
```

Comment: He doesn't want to load Map :D BTW, Nice name for the AsyncTask :)

Comment: So I call the getTracks() method in the doInbackGround but oncreate() I  set the listview adapter to the track array. But doing it this way when the listview adapter is set tracks is null because it hasn't been set by the async task!?

Comment: You can set ArrayAdapter in onCreate, and manipulate with adapter data only on PostExecute(), when all data is ready.