# Android database created list, how use in ListFragment

Tags: android, database, list, android-fragments, android-listfragment

well I am using my existing database, I made a list<> "mSorular" with this code:

```
public class TestAdapter {
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public TestAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}
    public List<soru> getTestData() {

    List<soru> mSorular = new LinkedList<soru>();
            try {
                Cursor mCur = mDb.query("Soru", null, null,
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

                if (mCur != null) {
                    if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            soru Soru = new soru();
                            Soru.setmSoru(mCur.getString(2));
                            Soru.setmCevap1(mCur.getString(3));
                            Soru.setmCevap2(mCur.getString(4));
                            Soru.setmCevap3(mCur.getString(5));
                            mSorular.add(Soru);

                        } while (mCur.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                return mSorular;
            } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>" + mSQLException.toString());
                throw mSQLException;
            }
        }
```

after that I want to use my mSorular list in a listfragment. When I try to

```
public class framelist extends ListFragment {
    private static String tag = "sqllist";

    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this);
```

it gives this error:

> The constructor TestAdapter(framelist) is undefined

without this my list will return empty. so how can I Use my list in this listfragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListFragment` is not a `Context`. First change it to use the attached `Activity` as `Context`, and then move it into the `onCreate()` method of the Fragment because before this call there might not be an `Activity` attached. (actually it's after the `onAttach(Activity)` call)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity());
    ...
{
```

Comment: Another version of a wise man is going... well can I ask another question. after that, making list take some time, can I show a loading screen until list be ready?

Comment: You sure can. You should move the long running task into an AsyncTask though. It will block the UI thread otherwise and make your app feel slow. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926157/android-progress-dialog-for-listview